# Clicking anchor tag doesn't position divs to the top of page

Tags: html, css, navigation, anchor

Having a problem with pretty simple website. It's a vertical scroll with a left side nav. When I click a menu item, it won't position the section to the top of the page. I've tried a few solutions from the community but it doesn't work with my setup.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U44Ut/

Here's a basic of the layout:

```
<div id=wrap">
     <div id="left">
         <div id="nav">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#item1">item 1</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div id="right">
         <div id="content">
             <div id="item1">CONTENT HERE</div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please reduce your JSFiddle code to the minimal amount required to reproduce this scenario? Further, why do you expect clicking an anchor tag to move a div?

Comment: Be specific you want to scroll to top of the page when clicked on The Company tag ??? or to the div

Comment: First of all, fix your HTML errors – your have `a` elements as children of `ul`, and you are using the ids `hero` and `text` multiple times.

Comment: Yes, user3127499 that is correct. I want to have the div that's identified by the anchor tag to move to the top of the browser when clicked. Any ideas as to why that might not be happening? Also, TylerH, I'll try and clean up that code in jsfiddle. One sec...

Comment: Here's the updated jsfiddle:: [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/U44Ut/9/)

Answer (score 2):

You're code is working properly, your problem is that the top of the elements you are linking to are not where you expect them to be.

This is the quick fix to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/U44Ut/8/

I put `<span id="">` tags around the text in your `<h1>` tags and linked to their id's. But you really should clean up your code.

Comment: That only solves the problem “by accident” … the real problem are the styles for the `#text` elements, that because of their `float:right` mess up the placement of the other elements …

Comment: Ya, Like I said, "quick fix," but code needs clean up.